# Use of execv with arbitrary commands of Linux — echo, date, ls, etc

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to understand the `execv()` function. Currently this is what I have.

```
int mish_command_name(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t id;
    int status;

    id = fork();
    switch( id ) {

    case -1: // the fork() failed
        perror( "fork" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    case 0: // we are the child process

        // if that failed, let's try /usr/bin
        execv( argv[0], argv );
        perror( "execv" );

        // use _exit() to avoid problems with the shared
        // stdout still being used by our parent
        _exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

        // will never reach this statement!
        break;

    default: // we are the parent
        break;

    }

    // parent will wait for child to exit
    id = wait( &status );
    if( id < 0 ) {
        perror( "wait" );
    } else {
        printf( "Parent: child %d terminated, status %d\n",
            id, status );
    }

    puts( "Parent is now exiting." );
    return 0;
}
```

Before I fork, I break the input up into tokens with this

```
void forkProcess(char* buff)
{
    //printf("%s\n", buff );
    char *ptrArray[10];
    int   ptrIndex = 0;
    char *cp = buff;
    ptrArray[ptrIndex++] = cp; 
    while((cp=strchr(cp, ' ')))
    {
        *cp = '\0';
        ptrArray[ptrIndex++] = ++cp;
    } 
    ptrArray[ptrIndex+1] = NULL;

    mish_command_name(ptrIndex, ptrArray);
}
```

When I enter something like '`echo hello world`', I get this.

```
mish[1]> echo hello
execv: No such file or directory
Parent: child 4511 terminated, status 256
Parent is now exiting.
mish[2]> echo hello world
execv: No such file or directory
Parent: child 4512 terminated, status 256
Parent is now exiting.
```

Some insight on how I'm messing this up here would be very helpful.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g`; then use `gdb` and `strace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply because `execv` requires a full path name. Try

```
/bin/echo foo
```

You can use `execvp` instead if you want to automatically search the PATH for your executable.

Comment: now when i run it it gives me a bad address error. Would you might know what that means?

Comment: You should verify that your ptrArray is correct. I'm guessing `ptrArray[ptrIndex+1]=NULL;` shouldn't have the `+1`, because the pointer was already incremented.